# Hidden Network causing Overlapping on my WiFi

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ssid

I am using inSSIDer and it is telling me that I have an overlapping network problem. Through further diagnosis, I have found the network with a similar frequency causing my lag and network issues. The problem is that it is a [Hidden] network. Does anyone have any experience with this issue and know a fix?

Also, is there a way to fix it when the router is in another apartment and I would preferably not want to bug the neighbors.

Comment: Can you use a different channel for your router and wireless card?  (I have inSSider here also)

Comment: Just switched channels. I still get the error, but I'll have to see through time if the wifi improves.

Comment: See what happens.  There is some chance (not a lot) that another nearby resident has the same MAC address. I have not seen this, but I have heard of it.

Comment: Any WiFi SSID may be "hidden", i.e. not broadcast it's name. That's a small security measure to make it slightly harder for an outsider to make use of someone else's service. See https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/hide-wifi-network-prevent-detected/ . Nothing to worry about, just try different channels to avoid interference in a crowded neighborhood.